Practices for Analyzing and Modifying Consumer Electronics
Long time lurker, first time poster.
I'm an Engineering student in my junior year and felt it would be good practice to analyze and modify consumer electronics, particularly with the goal of programmatically controlling sound/light as I also have some interest in music.
I picked a simple children's toy to start with and removed the circuit board. When trying to draw a representative diagram, I ran into some issues with being unable to characterize certain portions of the circuit (picture included)
My primary concern is this: There are multiple areas where several components have their connections somewhat obscured by, or possibly interconnecting with, a larger grid. I've indicated one of these with an orange arrow. For example, C7 seems like it links to the negative terminal with a single trace surrounded by many smaller traces, but it also looks as though it connects to C3.

Is there any more practical method of determining where connections lie other than removing each component? I expect because of the capacitors involved it would be difficult to just test for continuity, although there are many exposed points on the board that seem to be for that purpose.
Is there a convenient method to do any analysis on the microprocessor? I have read about some methods for removing resin blobs with fuming nitric acid, but those seemed to be in a context where the chip was fully removed.
Are there symbols or marks here I am missing that would indicate where an obscured connection is going?
Besides a multimeter, soldering iron, and microscope, are there any other tools that are necessary or beneficial for this kind of task?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you for your time


"several components have their connections somewhat obscured by, or possibly interconnecting with, a larger grid", "an obscured connection" - please clarify what you're referring to... this looks like a fairly standard high-volume single-sided PCB. The only obfuscation is under the "black blob", which will house a bare IC / piece of silicon. There's typically very little fun to be had with such designs, aside from triggering their existing functions and possibly steering a clock. I'd guess it's not even a microprocessor!

@Attie To clarify - One example for is at that orange arrow, where it seems as though C6 connects to C7 in series, which seems to connect to either a grid that leads towards the negative terminal, and/or C3. There is another pair, C5 and C4, immediately to the right of the blob, which I can't make heads or tails of where its going besides that it seems to be also connected to the speaker.
As a side note: It sounds like you have an idea of what designs might be easier to do exploration and study with?

Older consumer electronics can teach you some interesting tricks, especially in analog design. This question (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/705302/whats-this-vintage-diode-from-the-1970s) comes to mind. Not to say you can't find interesting stuff these days but I think there's a lot more "chip that does exactly what I want + reference design" going on.

@vir absolutely! I grew up taking old car radios apart – you could actually find the adjustable capacitors of the tuner! You could unsolder the amplifier IC and use it separately! You could tap into the audio line from tuner to amplifier and connect your own diskman to it and suddenly had loud sound! So much tinkering. I learned relatively little about electronics, and more about the hand craft of soldering, using a multimeter to find the 12 V DC supply on a board, how to not cut yourself on sharp metal edges, how to copy a schematic without understanding it…

@vir … and it was the right experience for me at that time. (I should probably have been more careful about ventilation? I remember coming out of the cellar, where the workbench I was doing this on was, with a headache, quite often.) But anyways, you see none of the "separately identifiable functionality" in the toy that the asker has :-( and if they were to take apart something less antiquely-designed (say, a cell phone): that's a complexity that takes a large reverse engineering team to understand, not a poor freshman.

As somebody who teaches instrumentation, I'd say there are inexpensive development boards with fully developed toolchains that would be a much more approachable way to learn "stuff".  Pick a goal you'd like to accomplish, research how to accomplish it, buy what you need to do it, then do it.  Then debug it.  You'll learn loads more than by messing with commercial products, and you'll develop an understanding of the fundamentals along the way.


felt it would be good practice to analyze and modify consumer electronics

uff! I'd say you're going into an engineering degree from the deep end; also, a pretty niche end: Most electrical engineers don't end up making consumer electronics.
And the problem with consumer electronics is: While still being based on the same physics and principles you learn at university, much effort flows into making them cheap. So cheap that you might not even recognize things anymore, or so cheap that things that you would generally consider good engineering practice are not done, at a high design effort invisible to you. You'd be in danger of learning from the wrong examples!
Speaking of wrong examples:
you found a toy in a least-cost variant. Thin, single sided phenolic paper instead of what you'd usually design (fiberglass PCBs with at least two layers), the practically only functionality-defining component hidden in a blob of epoxy, and that functionality completely hiding in an IC. There's not much you can learn from this, other than: this is what really cheap toy electronics look like.

Is there any more practical method of determining where connections lie other than removing each component? I expect because of the capacitors involved it would be difficult to just test for continuity, although there are many exposed points on the board that seem to be for that purpose.

You can look at the board with a strong light source behind, or use x-rays; commercial labs can polish off layer by layer of a board, where yours only has a single layer. (this is destructive, of course, but a company that pays another company to know the inner structure of a board probably has more complicated technical problems than inferring which connection goes where. Someone with a bit more experience – no offense, you're a junior, and so you have much to be taught, that's exciting, and not a fault – could pretty certainly just draw the top layer schematics up to the edge of the black blob from looking at it.

For example, C7 seems like it links to the negative terminal with a single trace surrounded by many smaller traces, but it also looks as though it connects to C3.

That "grid" is a "plane", and it's only "checkerboardy" because due to production constraints making it undesirable to have a closed large pane of copper on a cheap board. Also note that I don't think the plane does them any good. Unless there's circuitry on the other side of the board, it's an unmotivated plane with no advantage over a well-designed trace layout: the designers of this PCB (not the same as the designers of the circuit) might just not have been very motivated to deliver good work. Their salary probably was among the things "optimized". (The trace from the C3 footprint to the "-" connection, left in the plane pour, looks a like "I wasn't paid to make this pretty").
So, I'm not even sure you'd want to learn from this. A course on circuit design will teach you both easier and in depth what you can learn about circuits, and a workshop on PCB layout will probably teach you to build better electronics than this.

Is there a convenient method to do any analysis on the microprocessor? I have read about some methods for removing resin blobs with fuming nitric acid, but those seemed to be in a context where the chip was fully removed.

You need to dissolve the epoxy. These things are designed to be hard to resolve. Boiling nitric acid is among the nicer things you get to dissolve such.
Honestly, if you want to look at a board where you can work with the microcontroller, get a microcontroller evaluation board. These are meant for inspection, and also contain interfaces to actually talk to the thing, not just look at it. Things like ST Nucleo boards aren't very expensive (< $20).
Also, chances are this isn't a microprocessor at all, but a 1980s technology application-specific IC that does nothing but play back tones from a metal mask ROM in the IC itself. It's "hardwired"; these toys are so ubiquitous that this might actually be cheaper than buying a sufficient microcontroller, designing a software for it, and then soldering it in.

Are there symbols or marks here I am missing that would indicate where an obscured connection is going?

Aside from the black blob:
I don't see a single obscured connection! This is a single-layer board, all your components are "easy" in that the literally only components where signals run under a component are resistors labeled with "0" as in "0 Ω" as in "this is just a bridge over the 1 or 2 connections below; what enters left leaves right untouched".
So, nothing to analyze here.
Again, this is a very atypical example of a circuit board that you're likely to be asked to design.

Besides a multimeter, soldering iron, and microscope, are there any other tools that are necessary or beneficial for this kind of task?

This sounds more sarcastic than it is, but: your strongest tool here is courses studied in Electrical Engineering! If you were into commercial reverse engineering, you'd have a lot more tools, but as it stands now, you wouldn't know how to use them. That's the same as if you gave me a raster electron force microscope: I'm lacking the basics, the education and the practice in using one.
Equipping you with an oscilloscope wouldn't make you able to understand the circuit any better, even if it is a staple tool in an electronics lab. Because to understand what you're measuring with it, and what the hundreds of settings might do (to the oscilloscope, and to the circuit you're inevitably affecting by probing it), you need to have a somewhat solid foundation. So, bit more theory first, then the applied side of things makes a lot more sense :)

Any advice would be appreciated.

Enjoy your university year! Seriously! I started studying with 300 other EE students at the same time. I was pretty well-connected with the fellow students in my year, the year above and several years below (student council, and a lot of other things I did). None of them went on to design low-cost electronics (obviously not at university, because universities aren't in the business of selling cheap toys; a company that needs you to design cheap toys will happily hire you if you're a good designer and then teach you how to cost-optimize themselves). Some of them (like, easily 10, maybe 20 of >300) went on to design special purpose circuits for their final theses. Electrical engineering is so much more than building circuits on boards!
Knowing how circuits generally work, that's a necessary skill you get taught in university. But then you learn about how they work at RF frequencies, and how radio waves work, and how semiconductors work, and how computers work, and how information transport works, and how a controller (completely independent of whether you implement it as a PCB, a logic in a microcontroller, an ASIC, or a system of buckets and pipes) works and why, how the light in an LED gets created, how many types of electrical motors work (or a generator), how networks of wireless devices can communicate without blocking each other, how the power distribution grid works and how to optimize one, how an IC is manufactured in principle and in detail, how you measure things that are quantum, how you can improve the quality of an audio signal digitally… depending on in what you specialize (these are all examples from my university, which was especially broad for its size).
If you think about all these things, you'll realize that this is too much for a single head. So, you need to learn the basics that are useful for all these things. But you can't learn basics from looking at one super-specialized thing – and your toy definitely is super specialized!
I will not discourage you from tinkering with electronics – many of us have done that in parallel to their studies, whether they specialized in something that had to do with building circuits or not. It's awesome experience, and you can take a lot from it and transport it to other domains.
However, get yourself something that is meant for learning. I mentioned microcontroller evaluation boards, if you're into digital electronics / microcontrollers. You can get a breadboard and wire up an audio amplifier from an operational amplifier chip that can drive a small earphone (or you go for a chip that has more oomph, but then you'll need to know about a lot of things that you don't know yet to understand what you're doing). And then you can build an active filter out of your opamp and adjustable resistors, and then you build a bunch of them and build a multiband equalizer. Something like that.
But hoping to learn much from a board that's optimized for the opposite: sorry, that's like going to a meat processing plant to learn about the behaviour of chicken :(

I mostly agree.  More would be learned by making (copying from texts?) various circuits from scratch and then modifying those.  Electronic design varies so widely, as do the skills of the designer (don't assume they know what they're doing!), that who knows "what" is being learned by studying a given circuit that was mass-produced.

Still - keep taking stuff apart, perhaps not cheap items but more expensive stuff which is often discarded because the interface is obsolete. It's a good way of learning especially along the mecatronic design and if you have a whole family of items (think floppy disk drives or cd readers/writers/bluray) you can often see the progression of the designs as they get smaller and more advanced
